# How to solve error: The type or namespace name 'Phone' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I want to develop an app for Windows Phone 8 using the Speech functionality. I downloaded the examples presented here:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start-13-Speech-Input-in-Windows-Phone-8

but when I try to build the solution, I get this error "The type or namespace name 'Phone' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)".

I can see, in the object browser, the Microsoft.Phone assembly. Do I need something else? What am I missing?

Also another strange thing, is that Windows.Phone.Speech namespace is not visible in the object browser. Do I need to install another SDK for Windows.Phone.Speech ?

I am working with VisualStudio 2012 Professional and I installed the Windows Phone 8 SDK.

Comment: Did you add a reference for the assembly to your project?

Comment: I added it manually, no change. Shouldn't it be part of the .Net for Windows Phone references?

Comment: By installing the SDK it won't change any .NET assemblies. All it does is make new things available to you. You still need to add the new things to your project. Right-click the references folder and add it from there.

Comment: Of course, you also need the appropriate using statement(s).

Comment: I right-clicked on the references folder and added the corresponding dll, but the references folder is not changed, it contains only .Net for Windows Phone. I assume it is already included. I see it in the Object Browser, but the error remains.

Comment: If I create a WP8 project from the scratch, I don't have this problem anymore, but when I try to use the Speech.Synthesizer, by using Windows.Phone.Speech.Synthesis, the Speech namespace does not exist.

Comment: Thanks @Mithon for the hint. I solved the issue. I was referencing a wrong assembly. I had to add Windows.winmd Assembly, member of Windows Phone SDK 8.0

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an assembly reference.
Have you looked in Windows.winmd ?

Try this :

- Go to Object Browser
- Select "Windows Phone SDK 8.0" in Browse options (you should see the namespaces you are interesting in)
- Clic on the icon "Add to Reference in selected project in solution explorer" between arrow and setting icons.

It works for me.